# calling server methods with GET\POST from client in android Java

Tags: java, android, client-server, android-volley

I'm looking for a way to call methods from my android client (written in Java) in the server (instance of amazon ec2 written in Java). I'm looking for something like play framework, where I could write a GET request with a method name (lets say, calculateHighScore) and in the        routes.config I set the get method to execute calculateHighScore method from the server.

I have read about volley and its way of communication by JSON, but still I dont understand what should I write in the server side to execute a specific method and return an appropriate response.

Comment: Design a API for specific responses to `GET` and `POST` requests from android client.

Example : 

`test.com/api/?method="calculateHighScore"`

Extract params in the api and respond appropriately .

Comment: YES! That's what I was looking for! I dont know how to design an API, do you know a good guide/tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) RESTFul Services library.

For example on your server you could have some code like this:

```
@Path("/your_class")
public class YourClass {
    [...]
    @POST
    @Path("/your_method")
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public ArrayList<Object> yourMethod(String input){
        [...]
        return new ArrayList<Object>();
    }
}
```

And on the client side you could have some code like this:

```
[...]
ServiceFinder.setIteratorProvider(new AndroidServiceIteratorProvider());
ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
clientConfig.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);
clientConfig.getClasses().add(JacksonJsonProvider.class);
Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);

WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://yoursite.net:8080/NameOfService/rest/your_class/your_method");
ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json").post(ClientResponse.class,"your input");
ArrayList<Object> list = response.getEntity(new GenericType<ArrayList<Object>>() {});
[...]
```

Also [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html) is a good tutorial to help you with Jersey and its libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Design a API that handles responses to `GET` and `POST` requests from your android client. Api has to handle all the queries from the the android client.

For example if you want your overall `High Score` the client will send a request like this :

`test.com/api/?m="calculateHighScore"`

Now your api will extract parameters from your url and respond by sending a response with `High Score`.

You can read more about [API Design](http://codeplanet.io/principles-good-restful-api-design/) here. And more [here](http://apigee.com/about/api-best-practices/api-design/all).